# How to iterate through set of elements and check each if loaded before go to the next?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, each, setinterval

I guess I need some help with this. I have the following code that checks if an iframe (containing a google doc viewer document) on my page is loaded and if not reloads it until it finally has happened to be loaded.

```
function reloadIFrame() {
    // force iframe to reload   
    document.getElementsByClassName("preview-frame").src=document.getElementsByClassName("preview-frame").src;
}

timerId = setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 2000);

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.preview-frame').on('load', function() {
        clearInterval(timerId);
        console.log("Finally Loaded");
    });
});
```

In case someone is interested why: this is indeed needed because the Google Doc Viewer tends to not fully load the content (and then interrupts process) once in while and so you have only an 80% chance that content is actually shown instead of blank space.

The above code works fine but now I have the situation to have several iframes on my page.

What I want to achieve is kind of a loop that for each element starts a new interval until its content is loaded and then goes to the next one, until all iframes are reliably loaded and content is really displayed.

Someone with a helping hand how to achieve this? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new function and give the element you need to load as a parameter. Also call the callback after the element was loaded:

```
function loadIframe(iframeElement, callback) {
    function reloadIFrame() {
        // force iframe to reload   
        iframeElement.src = iframeElement.src;
    }

    timerId = setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 2000);

    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery(iframeElement).on('load', function() {
           clearInterval(timerId);
           callback(iframeElement);
        });
    });
}

// Here you can call the function
var iframes = document.getElementsByClassName("preview-frame");

for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length; i < len; i++) {
    loadIframe(iframes[i], function(element){
        console.log(element, 'finally loaded');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks first all! Looks really cool and seems logical to me. But sadly it throws an ocean of errors maybe due to the iframe nature (cross origin? I don’t know) among them also “ReferenceError: Can't find variable: reloadIFrame” which I actually do not understand.

Comment: @Garavani You could try to put the "reloadIFrame" function directly in the callback of the "setInterval" (as an anonymous function). This should fix the Reference Error.